# Переход со Swing на javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, swing

Как переписать проект со `Swing` на `JavaFX`? Придётся ли переписывать всё полностью или есть какие варианты, чтобы комплексно всё сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Увы, [серебряной пули](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bullet) нет...

Единственное, что могу сказать, что если миграция будет легкой, значит, приложение было хорошо спроектировано (view хорошо разделены от логики), а если нет, значит будет сложно.

[Интересная статья по миграции](https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~martin/blog/2018-11-12.html), погуглите на эту тему, ресурсов довольно много.

Comment: спасибо за статью!